# Please explain why List<A> cast to List<A.super> allowed or not allowed in Cpp, Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, c++, generics

I found that: Cpp, Java and C# have different control policies on cast from List of A to List of A.super. I know these three languages have different ways to implement Generics. Cpp use STL, Java use erasure, CLR's implementation is better. However, I can not tell why some casts allowed, while some casts are not allowed. For example:

1.Cpp

```
class A
{
protected:
    const char*_v;

public:
    A(const char* v)
    {
        _v = v;
    }

public:
    void getValue()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << _v << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(const char* v) :A(v)
    {
    }

public:
    void getValue()
    {
        std::cout << "B" << _v << std::endl;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::list<B> b;
    B b01("01");
    B b02("02");
    b.push_back(b01);
    b.push_back(b02);

    //no
    //std::list<A> a = static_cast <std::list<A> &>b;
    //no
    //std::list<A> a = dynamic_cast <std::list <A> & >b;
    //yes
    std::list<A> a = reinterpret_cast <std::list <A> &> (b);
    a.front().getValue();
    return 0;
}
```

2.Java

```
public static void testJava()
{
    List<String> s =  new ArrayList<String>();
    s.add("01");
    s.add("02");

    //no
    //List<Object> o = (List<Object>)s;

    //yes
    //List<Object> o = (List<Object>)(Object)s;
    //yes
    List<Object> o = (List<Object>)(List)s;
    System.out.println(o.get(0));
}
```

3.C#

```
    private static void testCS()
    {
        List<String> s = new List<String>()
        {
            "01",
            "02"
        };

        //no
        //List<Object> o = (List<Object>)s;

        //no
        //List<Object> o = (List<Object>)(Object)s;

        //yes, but I think this is a new List
        List<Object> o = s.OfType<Object>().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(o[0]);
    }
```

Can you explain that to me?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't cast a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>` in Java because you can add an `Object` to a `List<Object>`, but not to a `List<String>`.

Comment: You "yes" is "no", at least for C++ and probably for Java and C#. Just because you tortured the compiler into accepting the code doesn't mean that it will work correctly.

Comment: Because Java and C# don't let you shoot yourself in the foot in this way, but C++ allows you to make as many copies of your foot as you like, and shoot yourself in all of them simultaneously...

Comment: It is 3 distinct question. It will be easier to answer them separately

Comment: @talex it'd be easier to mark them as 3 separate duplicates, I think :)

Comment: @AndyTurner But I can convert List<String> to a List then to a List<Object>. Why?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, I am torturing the compiler. But I tested these small examples, they do work.

Comment: @neohope because a `List` is a raw type, and the compiler no longer knows the restrictions on the elements' type; it *might* be safe to convert to a `List<Object>`, so it allows the cast, just with a warning.

Comment: Each case, it is so because the language designers decided to implement it this way :) So, what are the pros and cons for each case? Well, that's really a far-fetched question...

Comment: @MatthewWatson So you mean that, that's a matter of language design?

Comment: @neohope Yes, but I explain properly in my answer below. My comment above was a bit tongue-in-cheek. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that C# and Java are preventing you from making a nasty mistake, but C++ allows you to do it (because of the way the language was designed).

Here's some sample C++ code that demonstrates what can go wrong. It is very similar to your example code with a small tweak: After casting the `list<B>` to `list<A>` it then pushes an element of type `A` onto the list. It then tries to access that element via the existing `list<B>` with predictable results (i.e. it explodes in your face):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class A
{
protected:
    const char*_v;

public:
    A(const char* v)
    {
        _v = v;
    }

public:
    void getValue()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << _v << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(const char* v) :A(v)
    {
    }

public:
    void getValue()
    {
        std::cout << "B" << _v << std::endl;
    }

    void thisIsOnlyInB()
    {
        std::cout << "Only in B" << _v << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<B> b;
    B b01("01");
    b.push_back(b01);

    std::list<A> a = reinterpret_cast <std::list <A> &> (b);

    A a01("01");
    a.push_back(a01);

    b.front().thisIsOnlyInB(); // OK - item is really a B.
    b.pop_front();
    b.front().thisIsOnlyInB(); // Oh dear - item is really an A, so this explodes.

    return 0;
}
```

This kind of problem was well-understood at the time that C# and Java were designed, and the language designers decided to fix it by issuing a compiler error.

C++ has always had a philosophy of "trust the programmer", so it allows you to do the cast - it's up to the programmer to ensure that it is not abused. (It's open to debate whether C++ would be designed differently in this area had it been invented later than it was. Some of the design decisions were perhaps a result of the state of compiler technology at the time.)

Comment: Well I would say that anything with a reinterpret cast in it should be very closely scrutinized, because using it usually wrong (as obvious in this case)

Comment: Oh, there's no doubt that C++ even today would have "trust the programmer" as a principle. It's a language that you can write an OS in, and that is intentional. There are dangerous constructs. On the flip side, unlike C these constructs stand out. The dangerous cast doesn't take just a type name and a parentheses pair (as C does), but a long keyword. There's a clear warning to readers that something unusual is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Because the generic/templated `List` type is *invariant* by its nature and your intention is to use it as a *covariant* type.

You can use any object of type B where A is expected because type B is a subtype of A. Because of this relation you (wrongly) expect  that any generic type to preserve this relation too. So in the `List<T>` example you expect that you can use any `List<B>` where `List<A>` is expected, but this is not possible because you cannot **guarantee the correctness of a program**, since suddenly `List<B>` can be altered with `A`.

C++, Java and C# have the notions of covariance, contravariance (the inverse of the „expected”) or invariance.

If you remove the Add method from the List interface then you might be able to build a covariant type because now this type doesn't have a method which might break the correctness of the List type, so in a list of B objects to unwillingly appear a `cousin` object of type C. But List without an Add makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is basically in what templates/generics do.

Though your example from C# does not seem to do a cast but create a new list.
Java I am not sure but it has some runtime checks which c++ does not generate due to performance overhead.

Also what you need to consider is that c++ templates actually generate the code. So when you instantiate a `std::list<typeA>` a list-class will be generated which is a completely different and unrelated class to a list with another class as template argument (even with a base class), so they cannot be casted into each other.